# webpack can't use process env variables in my angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I want to set API URL during webpack configuration.

Tried it like this :

```
plugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                hash: true,
                filename: 'index.html',
                template:  './src/index.ejs',
                inject : false
            }),
            // Write out CSS bundle to its own file:
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'css/styles.css',
                allChunks: true
            }),

            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.API':  'api'
            })
        );
```

and then in my JS tried calling it like this

```
const accountCentreAPI = process.env.API;
```

But get error as follows :

```
 http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from http://localhost:8080/
content is served from ./src
webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
{ SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:49)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (F:\src\Client\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (F:\src\Client\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (F:\src\Client\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
```

My webpack version
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.22

Note everything was working fine till I added DefinePlugin in my webpack and tried calling process.env in my js.

Comment: Can you share you webpack.config

Comment: fixed it, looks like i was just missing JSON.stringify() around the value in webpack.